# How to seal old stove vent hole in brick wall?

Tags: insulation, brick, hole, weatherstripping

We have an old stove vent that is no longer in use and now covered by drywall and cabinets on the interior, but the old exterior vent flap remains.  We opened the flap and were surprised to find a giant hole. The hole is pretty deep - it goes through the brick and cinderblock all the way to the interior drywall. We are concerned about moisture, insulation, and animals getting into the hole. The hole is about 8" in diameter and about 10" deep.  The house was built in 1950.  What is the best way to weatherize and seal the hole?  Thanks!

[image: picture of hole]

Comment: If you are sure you aren't going to reuse a vent there, brick it up.

Comment: But stuff some insulation in first.

Answer (score 3):

I pulled out the old vent. It was secured with mortar. I wound up using a sawsall to split the vent along one side, but I think it was the ensuing vibration that ultimately did the job. Once removed, I inserted insulation and glued and grouted a large piece of tile over the hole. I used terra cotta, as it most closely matched the color of the brick. I put two screws under the tile to hold it up and in place while it cured. I then glued and grouted a decorative tile onto the face of the large tile. The end result is very pretty and does not look like a "fix." My neighbor tried bricking it in, and while it doesn't look terrible, it definitely doesn't look flawless, as the bricks aren't exactly right and the mortar was not the right color.
Attached is a picture of the tile while it was curing -- I had to bump up the placement with that trowel to make it level.

PS> I was the first girl to take General Shop in my Jr. High School. #lifeskillz

[image: curing, before grout]

Comment: This looks very nice, and there's nothing wrong with a shim to get it level. Just don't forget to take it out. Are you the same person that asked this 4 years ago? If so [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) are directions to get your two accounts merged.